# Custom Javascript for existing Websites

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I would like to create an android application which views an existing web URL, However, i would also like the button controls on the android app to be able to run custom javascript code on the website's context.

Any ideas on how to make this happen? Perhaps extend or create a custon WebView?? Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browsers in general you can execute arbitrary javascript via url bar injection (also called bookmarklet if saved in bookmarks).

```
// first load your normal page, then do this
WebView.loadUrl("javascript: var x = 1; ");
```

You can test all this by pasting this in your desktop browser url bar `window.alert("hello")`.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot. How would i link some button on an android application (not necceseraily the same view) to a javascript function inside the webview though?